# How to fix moveable Div

Tags: html, css

I have created two div one is with class name .main and the second one is `.container`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  background-color: #cfeeec;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

When I am resizing the browser windows vertically the div with the class `.container` is changing its position. I want it to below the main div.

Comment: Is the `.container` element absolutely positioned for a reason? Because of you don't take it out of the document flow it'll be below the `.main` element by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your div positioned below the `.main` div (i.e. *relative* to the `.main` div), then you should refrain from using *absolute* positioning and use *relative* positioning instead. You can also not define a `position` property - by default it will be set to static, which also works:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #cfeeec;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, the .main will be below .container. And `position: absolute` will remove the element completely out of the document flow.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  background-color: #cfeeec;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Try this.